# please, how do I call a php webservice in java

Tags: java, php

this is my php webservice....

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET['PassKey'])) {

$PassKey = $_GET['PassKey'];

 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'database', 'password');
 mysql_select_db('databasename', $link) or die('error....could not connect');

 $query = "SELECT passkey, used FROM activation where passkey = $PassKey and used = 0";

 $result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die ('Errant query: ' .$query); 
 if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  $success = "success";
  echo json_encode(array("status" => $success));
  $finally = "UPDATE activation set used=1";
 }
 else {
  $failure = "failure";
  echo json_encode($failure);
 }
}
```

my java activate code

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package PastQuestions;


/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class Activate extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Activate
     */
    public Activate() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Validate App");

        jTextField1.setName("PassKey"); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 0, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("Activate Your App First");

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bradley Hand ITC", 3, 24)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 204));
        jButton1.setText("Validate");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(63, 63, 63)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 317, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(111, 111, 111)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 168, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(44, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(81, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Activate.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Activate.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Activate.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Activate.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

my problem here is calling the php webservice to work inside the java code. i am a really novice in this.
please, how do i call the webservice in the java app. thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an HTTP connection from Java to your php server like this

```
    private static void sendGET(String GET_URL) throws IOException {
    URL obj = new URL(GET_URL);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("GET request not worked");
    }

}
```

More examples at http://www.journaldev.com/7148/java-httpurlconnection-example-java-http-request-get-post

Comment: @preprocessor please accept the solution if you are satisfied

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped

Answer (score 0):

The **HttpUrlConnection** class is used for all types of HTTP requests. You can find plenty of usage examples.

With this, your Java application will call over HTTP to server, where your PHP code running.